# How to differentiate multiple GenericForeignKey relation to one model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, generic-foreign-key

I have the following model structure:

```
class Uploadable(models.Model):    
    file = models.FileField('Datei', upload_to=upload_location, storage=PRIVATE_FILE_STORAGE)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')


class Inspection(models.Model):
    ...
    picture_before = GenericRelation(Uploadable)
    picture_after = GenericRelation(Uploadable)
```

I wonder how I can tell that one file was uploaded as a `picture_before` and another as `picture_after`. The `Uploadable` does not contain any information about it.

Googled around for some time but did'nt find a proper solution.

Comment: Take a look at using [reverse relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations) using `related_query_name`. It won't tell you if the Uploaded instance is a before or after but it will allow you to fetch either the befores or afters from the Uploaded instance using the reverse relation.

Comment: I did that but where is the information which picture is a "before" and which a "after" picture? It needs to be persisted in the DB somewhere, right?

Comment: Let's say your Uploaded instance is `pic` and  `related_query_name="before_pics" ` on the `picture_before` relation. Querying `pic.before_pics` will return a queryset of pictures that are befores.

Comment: But where is the information in the database that Uploadable 1 is a "before"? The Uploadable class has only three records and the inspection class zero related to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is only one way to do it. You'll need to create an additional attribute in the generic model so you can persist the context.

I got the idea [from this blog post](https://ken-dev.info/django-tricks/2018/11/30/django-generic-relation.html):

```
class Uploadable(models.Model):
   
    # A hack to allow models have "multiple" image fields
    purpose = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class Inspection(models.Model):
    ...
    images = GenericRelation(Uploadable, related_name='inspections')
    ...
    
    @property
    def picture_before(self):
        return self.images.filter(purpose='picture_after')
    
    @property
    def picture_after(self):
        return self.images.filter(purpose='picture_after')
```